# How to level up in Diablo 3 2.0.1?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new patch 2.0.1, I'm level 60 and I can't get to level 61. I keep getting paragon levels, but I can't get "normal" levels to get to level 70. How can I gain "normal" XP to actually level up?

Comment: The expansion hasn't come out so you can't get to 70 yet.

Comment: This is a useful answer. Thanks. But we were several amongst my friends to ask it, so it seems legitimate. So why the downvotes. If you downvote, you should explain why.

Comment: Questions about unreleased content are downvoted and generally closed. I am actually not sure why this open still. Maybe because we can just assume the answer is 'Just play the expansion when it comes out.'??

Comment: @James This question is, "I have the new patch, so why can't I level up to 70?", which has nothing to do with unreleased content.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Level 70 is part of the expansion that is coming out I believe?

Comment: @James It is. But asking why they can't access that in their current game doesn't mean they're asking about unreleased content. "Why can't I hit level 70?" "Because level 60 is the max in the base game, even after the patch".

Comment: There are several references to the level 70 in the 2.0.1 patch notes. So the confusion is understandable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Level 70 is tied to the upcoming expansion, Reaper of Souls (as is the Crusader class and a few other things).

Many of the rest of the changes were released in patch 2.0.1, and while it was released in preparation for the expansion, they are not related, and everyone who owns the base game will be able to enjoy their benefits (as you and your friends have experienced).

World of Warcraft (a small Blizzard game you may have heard of) works in a similar way, with a "pre-expansion patch" that contains the major system changes that were decided to be released alongside the expansion.

Comment: Well, I've heard of WoW, lots of friend play it, but I never played it firsthand (not a fan of subscription). So I'm not familiar with this habit at all. I think they should be more clear about what is in the patch and what is in the expansion. The patch has clear mentions of the level 70 while not having the text "the level cap is now 70". This is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to have the Reaper of Souls expansion either installed or at least linked to you account to get to level 70.
After Paragon 2.0 goes live, if you are level 60 and do not have the Reaper of Souls enabled on your account, you will continue to earn Paragon experience in the new system. This is because you are still technically at the level cap. However, if you are level 60 and decide to enable the expansion on your account, you will stop earning Paragon experience. This is because the expansion increases the level cap to 70. Once you reach level 70, you will start to accrue Paragon experience again from where you left off. (So, basically: Only max-level characters will be able to earn Paragon experience. If you don't have the expansion, max-level = 60. If you have the expansion, max-level = 70.)

Comment: Even if you currently own Reaper of Souls, you still can't get to level 70 right now.  That only activates when the expansion does, which is in a couple of weeks.

Comment: This is a valid answer I don't understand the down vote